# Bluemix essentials Eclipse Neon Enide.p2f NodeEclipse 1.0.1 / 1.0.2 Unhandled event loop HTTP Server Unknown code 499 404 compositeContent.xml

Tags: node.js, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud, eclipse-neon

I'm trying to do IBM Bluemix essential course.
As per the course instructions, I installed Eclipse (I initially got latest Eclipse version **Neon** instead of Mars but tried both Mars and Neon as of now for installing NodeEclipse .17, 1.0.1 or 1.0.2 or Enide.p2f file using both File import and Eclipse marketplace for installing Enide.p2f Node eclipse plugin in Eclipse).

One of the instruction (after installing IBM Bluemix plugin for eclipse) says, I need to install "Enide.p2f Eclipse NodeJS plugin" https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enidep2f-eclipse-nodejs-ide

I tried Eclipse Marketplace to install this. Searched "node eclipse" and selected the top listing entry for "Nodeeclipse 1.0.2 Nodeeclipse Core & Node.js (nodeeclipse-1)" or even "Enide.p2f for Nodeeclipse 1.0.1" version and clicked installed.

A couple of times, if failed during the resolution process to list the plugin components and Eclipse error log showed that the update site / repository server was not available.

Another method was to install the .p2f file directly File > Import > Install > Install from a file and selected the downloaded .p2f file which I got from here:  https://raw.github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/master/ENodeIDE.p2f
or
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-eclipse-nodejs-ide/click

Using the import > install via file method, I'm getting "Unhandled event loop exception" error message as per Eclipse Error logs and it didn't install anything.

Using the market place method, I'm getting the following error mesg (per the screen shot):

For Nodeeclipse 1.0.1
https://i.imgsafe.org/1b1bf4f0fb.jpg

https://i.imgsafe.org/1b1be1c00a.jpg

https://i.imgsafe.org/1b1bc75cfc.jpg

For Nodeeclipse 1.0.2.
https://i.imgsafe.org/1afbf9bf56.jpg

https://i.imgsafe.org/1afa90e4f1.jpg

https://i.imgsafe.org/1af372340c.jpg

**Error message**:
HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (499):http://nodeeclipse.org/updates/compositeContext.xml
   HttpComponents connection error response code 499.

OR

it shows the Enide.p2f .17, 1.0.1 or 1.0.2 (Whichever you select from the list) to install the plugin:

```
The following solutions are not available: Nodeclipse 1.0.2
(id=markdown.editor.feature.feature.group,  
org.nodeclipse.pluginslist.feature.feature.group, 
gitaddon.feature.feature.group, 
de.bastiankrol.startexplorer.feature.feature.group, 
com.eclipsesource.jshint.feature.feature.group, 
org.nodeclipse.feature.group, 
org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.jade.feature.feature.group,  
org.chromium.sdk.feature.group, net.mihai-nita.ansicon.feature.group, 
org.chromium.debug.feature.group, 
pm.eclipse.editbox.feature.feature.group, 
site=http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/)
```

With Eclipse Mars, I'm getting the same behavior. More info on this can be found here as well: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=76a96fa4-1086-41a7-94a6-4326f79dfacb&ps=#repliesPg=0

Did anybody else face this similar issue and what should i do to resolve it.

Comment: "https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enidep2f-eclipse-nodejs-ide"looks like an update site so I tried the Help->Install New Software... I then entered the address as a new update site but it failed as well...

Answer (score 0):

"https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enidep2f-eclipse-nodejs-ide"looks like an update site so I tried the Help->Install New Software... I then entered the address as a new update site but it failed as well...